# Webmin Scheduled Cron Job Not working

Tags: yii, cron, scheduled-tasks, cron-task, webmin

I have a cron job scheduled on my VPS, which runs at manual execution but not when scheduled as a cron job.

[image]

Command

```
/usr/bin/php -q  /var/www/html/cron.php notification  sendChatNotication (*yii)
```

is working as expected on shell.

I have followed configuration settings as below.

http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Scheduled_Cron_Jobs